# Как поставить точку завершения дебага в Xdebug?

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

Можно ли в Xdebug поставить точку, до которой будет выполнятся отладка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да точка останова называется.

После последней точки сбросятся все переменные и можно сказать, что отладка завершена.